# Take snapshot from UIScreen

Tags: ios, swift

I want to take a snapshot from view including the status bar.

the code below works in the simulator but doesn't on a physical device.

```
extension UIScreen {

    class func screenshot() -> UIImage {
        let view = main.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: false)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size)
        view.drawHierarchy(in: view, afterScreenUpdates: true)

        let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return screenshot!
    }
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile, did you mean to call `view.drawHierarchy(in: view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to fix your problem you can use this function:

```
func takeScreenshot() -> UIImage? {
    var screenshotImage :UIImage?
    let layer = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.layer
    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, scale);
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {return nil}
    layer.render(in:context)
    screenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return screenshotImage
}
```

I just tested this and it works on a physical device.

Answer (score 0):

Create a extension like:

```
extension UIApplication {

    func getViewScreenShot(vc: UIViewController) -> UIImage? {

        let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
        let bounds = vc.view.bounds
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, scale)
        if UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() != nil {
            vc.view.drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
            let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
            return screenshot!
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

And call it like:

```
weak var weakSelf = self
let screenShotImage: UIImage = UIApplication.shared.getViewScreenShot(vc: weakSelf!)
```